# Implement 1-ply, 2-ply or 3-ply search td-gammon

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I've read some articles and most of them say that 3-ply improves the performance of the self-player train. 
But what is this in practice? and how is that implemented?

Answer (score 0):

There is stochasticity in the game because of the dice rolls, so one approach would be evaluate state positions by self play RL, and then while playing do a 2-ply search over all the possible dice combinations. That would be 36 + 6 i.e. 42 possible rolls, and then you have to make different moves that are available which increases the breath of the tree to an insane degree. I tried this and it failed because my Mac could not handle such computation. Instead what we could do is just randomize a few dice rolls and perform a MiniMax tree search with Alpha Beta pruning ( using the AfterState value function).

For a 1 ply search we just use the rolled dice, or if we want to predict the value before we roll the dice then we can simply loop over all the possible combinations. Then we just argmax over the afterstates.